# Can I implement Both onClicklistener and onItemClickListener in single activity?

Tags: android

in calculator example I've calculate by buttons and radio buttons so Can I implement Both onClicklistener and onItemClickListener in single activity?

Comment: yes you can implement it

Comment: Yes? But why are you asking? is there something dont let you do it?

Comment: Is there any problem while implementing both in single activity?

Comment: So what is the problem? You can do it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, May be you are confuse with `Both Listener`. But [onClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) is use to `getClick` on some specific view, like view control `Button ,Text ,ImageButton` etc.

While [OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) is use to getClick on child view , like `ListView`, Listview is parent view and when you want to do some task on click of list row at that time you should use OnItemClickListener.

I hope now you are clear with you question.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer to your simple question: **Yes, you can do it**.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements onClickListener, onItemClickListener {
// 
//
}
```